# jAlert - Alert does not center correctly on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I am using [jAlert](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/) to display an alert on bad input.  The popup displays roughly 300px from the top.  The user may experience an error roughly 2000px down the page, in an area where the popup is not visible.  In cases such as this the user doesn't even know the popup occured.

Ideally, the popup should display in the center of the current visible screen area.  But, Scrolling up to the top is the next best thing.  I'm unsure how to implement either.

The method does not appear to have an overload to accept screen location coordinates.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jAlert("Flippin message", "Title");//, function () {
       // alert('normal alert');//optional callback
    //});
});
```

How can I best solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE**
Things work fine in IE/Firefox/Safari(desktop).  The issue is just with iPads browser.

Comment: jAlert seems to display the dialog in the center of the viewport by default. What's different about your page? How about a demo?

Comment: @Matt Ball - This may be an environment specific problem. The issue occurs on iPad.  Updated question to reflect this fact.

Comment: Does the jAlert demo page behave the same way as your page on iPad? (Sorry, I don't have one to try it myself. Happy to buy one, provided the funds, though...)

Comment: @Matt Ball - Confirmed - Works fine in firefox/IE, but fails on iPad.

Comment: I am facing this issues too...any luck/workaround for this?

Comment: @zoom_pat277 - We switched back to the standard DOM alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked into the plugin code and changed this line

```
if( $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 ) top = top + $(window).scrollTop();
```

to

```
if( $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) <= 6 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) top = top + $(window).scrollTop();
```

This seems to work for ipad... and is opening the alert at the center even if I have scrolled my way down the page... Hope it helps... please suggest if there is a better solution...